# Is there any common unique id or variable existing in Facebook and Twitter (like email)?

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is there any common unique id or variable existing in Facebook and Twitter like email id? .Currently i developing a social game ,which can login with Facebook , Twitter and  using email id.

Problem is

1.Facebook provide email but Twitter 
2.Facebook and Twitter provides id , but both are different not same value

Comment: No, there is no overall identifier. Even the email you get from different platforms might be different, simply because the user might have used  different emails to sign up for those platforms.

Comment: Thank you CBroe  for your reply , anybody have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no unifying link between Facebook accounts and Twitter accounts. As stated in the comment by @Cbroe even using e-mail is not a valid link since they could use different e-mail address on different accounts.

You will have to allow the user to authenticate to both in order for you to internally track which of your users belongs to each Facebook/Twitter account.